# How to calculate Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension?

Tags: machine-learning

I got stuck with this problem:

Given just a $$X=\{1,2,3,4\}$$ and a $$C=\{\{1,3,4\},\{4\},\{2,3\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$$

how do I calculate VC dimension of C?

I know that for example with $$S=\{1,2,3\}$$ given in the prior problem would easily lead me to the end. 
This because $$S \subseteq X$$ So I would just have to verify if $$|S\cap C|$$ (known as the cardinality of the intersection) can be decomposed in a "2 power of D". 
So given $$|S \cap C| = 8$$ since $$8 = 2^3$$
I will have $$D=3$$ and if $$|S| = D \to VCdim(C)\ge D$$

This because by definition

$$VCdim(C)=max\{D|\exists S, |S|=D, |\pi_c(S)=2^D\}$$
$$|\pi_c(S)|=\{c_i\cap S| c_i\in C\}$$
where $$|\pi_c(S)|$$ is the cardinality of the intersection.

The problem that I'm facing is: if the S is not given, how can I find a legit S, which by definition I know it is the biggest set that can be shattered from C?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please give us an example of $C$ where you can solve the problem and another example where you cannot. And what does $S$ have to do with anything?

Comment: Edited with a legit example.